# Nexus fails starting: Unable to set localhost

Tags: macos, dns, localhost, ehcache, nexus

I am trying to install and run [Nexus](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/index.html) on MacOS via *homebrew*. The installation went fine so far. Version 2.13 was installed.

The following error occurs when I start via `nexus console`:

```
ERROR [jetty-main-1] *SYSTEM net.sf.ehcache.Cache - Unable to set localhost. 
This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: 
87.128.123.10.dyn.in-addr.arpa: 87.128.123.10.dyn.in-addr.arpa

java.net.UnknownHostException: 87.128.123.10.dyn.in-addr.arpa: 87.128.123.10.dyn.in-addr.arpa
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1475) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:217) ~[ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:303) [ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:219) [ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:648) [ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.doInit(CacheManager.java:407) [ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:357) [ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:242) [ehcache-core-2.5.1.jar:na]
    at org.sonatype.sisu.ehcache.CacheManagerComponentImpl.createCacheManager(CacheManagerComponentImpl.java:112) [nexus-ehcache-2.13.0-01.jar:2.13.0-01]
    at org.sonatype.sisu.ehcache.CacheManagerComponentImpl.<init>(CacheManagerComponentImpl.java:57) [nexus-ehcache-2.13.0-01.jar:2.13.0-01]
    at org.sonatype.sisu.ehcache.CacheManagerComponentImpl.<init>(CacheManagerComponentImpl.java:52) [nexus-ehcache-2.13.0-01.jar:2.13.0-01]
    at org.sonatype.sisu.ehcache.CacheManagerComponentImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$6e60c0a8.newInstance(<generated>) [sisu-guice-3.1.10.jar:2.13.0-01]
    ...
```

When I open `http://localhost:8081` this 404 error page is shown to me:

[image: Nexus error page]

The `hostname` command outputs:

> 87.128.123.10.dyn.in-addr.arpa

The `ifconfig en0` command outputs:

> en0: flags=8863 UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST mtu 1500
>     options=10b
>     ...
>     inet 10.123.128.87 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 10.123.131.255
>     nd6 options=1
>     media: autoselect (100baseTX )
>     status: active

Comment: Did you check hosts file entries against your hostname?

Comment: What should I look for? I looked into `/etc/hosts`. It contained an entry for `127.0.0.1 localhost`. I added `0.0.0.0 localhost`. No difference, though.

Comment: Please try adding adding local IP mapping in hosts.
Can you please share ip's listed in ifconfig output and hostname output?

Comment: Don't add `0.0.0.0 localhost`! that's [a non-routable meta address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) that cannot be used that way in your `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: Looks like ehcache is attempting to perform a reverse DNS lookup (the `in-arpa.addr` part tells us this) of your IP, and DNS has nothing, which causes java to toss a UnknownHostException in your case. (which is really bizarre)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I removed it. Thanks. About the reverse lookup .. strange ... so what now?

Comment: The DNS _might_ have had something without the `dyn` label immediately preceding the `in-addr.arpa` domain - there's no such domain as `dyn.in-addr.arpa`.   That said, you're using 10/8 from RFC 1918 so even then you'd still get a "no such host" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nexus runs on the /nexus context by default so please try http://localhost:8081/nexus

The 404 page is returned by Jetty so the app server is running fine and everything should be okay.

And if localhost does not work try with your IP number or with 127.0.0.1

Comment: I will try this on Monday as soon as I sit on this Mac again. Thanks so far for the clarification.